# Camunda Subprocess

Tags: camunda, camunda-modeler

I am a newbie to Camunda.
Wanted to know if it is possible to have multiple instances of a subprocess and if this subprocess can be started at any point in time during the execution of the main process?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is an event sub process https://docs.camunda.io/docs/components/modeler/bpmn/event-subprocesses/

> An event subprocess is a subprocess triggered by an event. This can be added globally to the process, or locally inside an embedded subprocess.

It can be triggered any time during execution of the main process and it can be interrupting or non-interrupting. The start event, can be a message, timer or error (in Camunda 8). In Camunda 7 there are more supported start events. See here https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.17/reference/bpmn20/subprocesses/event-subprocess/